# Show profile info from a User/ Laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel, view, laravel-blade

I'm trying to make a view profile from the user that is currently using the web, the thing is that The route apparently is not working.

I create a perfilController file and in there there is a function called show

```
class PerfilController extends Controller
{
    public function show($id) {
        $users = DB::select('select * from users where id = ?',[$id]);
        return view('alumno.profile',['users'=>$user]);
    }
}
```

and in my web file i have this

```
 Route::get('show/{id}', 'PerfilController@show')->name('show_profile');
```

The error that gives me is that the page could not be found

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dglmj.png)

Comment: show whole error message

Comment: Why do you try to go to `alumno/profile`? Try like this `/show/1`

Comment: show your html code in which you pass **id** parameter in the url.

Comment: You are calling your `route` incorrectly. Check with this url `http://127.0.0.1:8000/show/1` assuming `1` is `id` of a `user` record in your database

Answer (score 0):

If you pass correct **id** from html code in the url for this route then you can do the following:

```
class PerfilController extends Controller
{
    public function show($id) {
        $users = DB::table('users')->where('id','=',$id)->get();
        return view('alumno.profile', compact('users', $users));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
class PerfilController extends Controller
{
    public function show($id) {

        $users = DB::table('users')->where('id',$id)->get();
        return view('alumno.profile',compact('users'));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look into Eloquent and Route Model Binding so you wouldn't have to use raw queries for something so simple. 
You also need a get() on the end of your query to actually run the query

Answer (score 0):

the route looks fine 
and just to make the synatx smaller you can use

```
$data = modelname::find($id);
```

then pass it to the view

```
return view('view name')->with('data' , $data);
```

but i think the main problem is in you html file maybe you wrote the file route incorrectly in your controller or something like this